# Can one include a cmake toolchain file rather than passing it as a command line argument?

Tags: cmake

So, when I include the toolchain file sometimes it is a hit and sometimes it is a miss. I'm able to build a target and all but the problem is that I'm not able to launch the target in vscode or clion. The error verbose reads unable to find the target.

Is there something wrong with including the toolchain file?

Comment: "Is there something wrong with including the toolchain file?" - If you include the toolchain file with `include()` command, then this is definitely **wrong**. In CMake a toolchain file should be set via `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` variable.

Comment: BTW you may assign variable `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` in `CMakeLists.txt` too. Just make sure that the assignment precedes any `project()` or `enable_language()` calls.